# Can I put an in-list statement and an if statement in one line in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to condense my code a bit and put if-else statements on single lines. When I try and do this for an if-else statement that includes an in-list statement, I get an error.

```
temperature = 10 if 'hi' in ['hi','2'] else temperature = 1

  File "<ipython-input-2-af6c452397be>", line 1
    temperature = 10 if 'hi' in ['hi','2'] else temperature = 1
                 ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression
```

Comment: You need to use `==` as `=` is an assignment statement.

Answer (score 1):

This will accomplish what you intend:

```
temperature = 10 if 'hi' in ('hi', '2') else 1
```

By the way, the condition `'hi' in ('hi', '2')` is always `True`, what's the point of it?